# How to make CSS3 column displays work in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-multicolumn-layout

This works in FF/Chrome/Opera, and IE 10+, but not IE9; I'm looking for an IE9 solution

The following CSS will to make a set of divs, span, or p tags self-organize into neat columns that can be scrolled horizontally (Only works in WebKit enabled browsers).

```
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-webkit-column-width: 300px;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-width: 300px;
-moz-column-gap: 40px;
```

Here is the example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".RightArrow ").click(function() {
    $(".columns").animate({
      scrollLeft: '+=500'
    }, 100);
  });

  $(".LeftArrow ").click(function() {
    $(".columns").animate({
      scrollLeft: '-=500'
    }, 100);
  });



}); //end script
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
.columns {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: 300px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-width: 300px;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.notsectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.arrows {
  width: 500px;
}
.RightArrow {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.LeftArrow {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns">



  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">1</span>
NUM 1
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>


  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">2</span>
NUM 2
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>

  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">3</span>
NUM 3
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>



  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">4</span>
NUM 4
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>


  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">5</span>
NUM 5
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>

  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">6</span>
NUM 6
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>

</div>
<!--columns-->


<div class="arrows">


  <span class="LeftArrow"> Previose </span>  <span class="RightArrow">  Next </span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n5qh89vw/

The reason I want it to work this way is I have straight output from a DB into a list of `<div>` s and I would like to avoid having to make it more complicated and have to have the output count the number of data items then form the markup into inline divs or tables (as in x number cells will make y columns with rows of 4) as I want to keep this as simple as possible.

Is there a way to get this to work with IE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), Multiple column layout is supported in IE 10+. If you need to support older versions of IE there is a [CSS multicolumn polyfill](https://github.com/hamsterbacke23/multicolumn-polyfill) (found in the Resources tab at Can I Use).

Now that you've updated your question to specify that you need this for IE9, here is a full example using [Adam Wulf's Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/path-to-local-file/jquery.columnizer.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('.wide').columnize({width:400});
                $('.thin').columnize({width:200});
            });
        </script>

    <style>
        .column p, .column h1{ padding: 5px; }
        body { font-size: 9pt; }
        #wrapper { margin: 0px 100px; }
        .wide, .thin { clear:both; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="wide">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum ne justo</h1>
            <p>Bonorum has. His ut cibo quas tantas, vis ut probo adhuc definiebas, has at meis debet vulputate. No sed velit essent suavitate, in pro decore ceteros temporibus, usu in odio offendit theophrastus. Mel labore indoctum cu, ad soleat admodum delicatissimi sed, mei viris tritani ullamcorper eu. Ut vim simul aperiam.</p>
            <p>Eu eleifend repudiandae has. Mea eu ridens aliquam. Nisl aeque sit ut, posse dolor utinam cum in. Ad timeam sapientem eos, et eripuit inermis nam. Eos integre voluptaria ne, iriure concludaturque ut eum.</p>
            <p>Vis erant intellegat in. Soleat legere no ius, usu ex laoreet molestie. Sit eu sint inermis. Ea zzril scribentur pro.</p>
            <h1>Tempor essent appetere</h1>
            <p>Ius mutat commune expetendis in. Nam et quas sensibus reprimique, vix no erat soluta suavitate. At mel eius dictas latine. Corrumpit inciderint reformidans sed no, no usu omnis utinam noluisse.</p>
            <p>Sit et, an ius nihil apeirian. Eu posse tempor iuvaret cum. No diam dolor sea, postea mnesarchum ne ius, vel no utinam ignota dolores. Malis suscipit accusamus his ne, utinam assentior prodesset ea eam, facer partem antiopam et cum.</p>
            <p>Probo debet quaestio an eos, no mel assum iracundia delicatissimi, rebum facete utroque sed ex. Eu melius invidunt repudiandae vix, eu paulo reformidans deterruisset duo, solum voluptaria efficiantur ea mel. Qui summo zzril alienum et. Eu est ferri iuvaret, mazim epicurei sententiae ut cum, modo reque intellegat ex vix. Vim eu tibique accusamus, quot electram at qui.</p>
            <p>Ex iisque eleifend periculis has. Sit aeterno virtute partiendo ei, eam nonumy bonorum adolescens ad. Ut nec suas vocent ornatus, cetero legendos constituam mea ea, pri cu delenit iracundia. Mundi decore nec te.</p>
            <h1>Soleat civibus in pri</h1>
            <p>In petentium erroribus percipitur per. Takimata accommodare ius ut, eam no postulant urbanitas. Qui ei tantas consectetuer, quis dictas euripidis duo ei. Quaeque democritum concludaturque has ne.</p>
            <p>Blandit insolens constituto vix an. Has diam wisi in, eum unum repudiare no. Sit at virtute rationibus, qui vitae explicari cu. Vim ne singulis voluptatum, sed puto accusata salutandi ei. Ad mel civibus adversarium.</p>
            <p>Per ne solum vivendo, fabulas dolorem vivendo in pro. Nec duis ignota cotidieque no, an per possit nostrum. Pro detraxit definitionem eu. Vivendo officiis no nam, eu has reque maiestatis percipitur, dolore reprimique accommodare cum ad. No utinam voluptua oportere pri, augue sonet dicant ei sea.</p>
            <p>Sit et, an ius nihil apeirian. Eu posse tempor iuvaret cum. No diam dolor sea, postea mnesarchum ne ius, vel no utinam ignota dolores. Malis suscipit accusamus his ne, utinam assentior prodesset ea eam, facer partem antiopam et cum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="thin">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum ne justo</h1>
            <p>Bonorum has. His ut cibo quas tantas, vis ut probo adhuc definiebas, has at meis debet vulputate. No sed velit essent suavitate, in pro decore ceteros temporibus, usu in odio offendit theophrastus. Mel labore indoctum cu, ad soleat admodum delicatissimi sed, mei viris tritani ullamcorper eu. Ut vim simul aperiam.</p>
            <p>Blandit insolens constituto vix an. Has diam wisi in, eum unum repudiare no. Sit at virtute rationibus, qui vitae explicari cu. Vim ne singulis voluptatum, sed puto accusata salutandi ei. Ad mel civibus adversarium.</p>
            <p>Ius mutat commune expetendis in. Nam et quas sensibus reprimique, vix no erat soluta suavitate. At mel eius dictas latine. Corrumpit inciderint reformidans sed no, no usu omnis utinam noluisse.</p>
            <p>Probo debet quaestio an eos, no mel assum iracundia delicatissimi, rebum facete utroque sed ex. Eu melius invidunt repudiandae vix, eu paulo reformidans deterruisset duo, solum voluptaria efficiantur ea mel. Qui summo zzril alienum et. Eu est ferri iuvaret, mazim epicurei sententiae ut cum, modo reque intellegat ex vix. Vim eu tibique accusamus, quot electram at qui.</p>
            <p>Eu eleifend repudiandae has. Mea eu ridens aliquam. Nisl aeque sit ut, posse dolor utinam cum in. Ad timeam sapientem eos, et eripuit inermis nam. Eos integre voluptaria ne, iriure concludaturque ut eum.</p>
            <p>Sit et, an ius nihil apeirian. Eu posse tempor iuvaret cum. No diam dolor sea, postea mnesarchum ne ius, vel no utinam ignota dolores. Malis suscipit accusamus his ne, utinam assentior prodesset ea eam, facer partem antiopam et cum.</p>
            <p>Vis erant intellegat in. Soleat legere no ius, usu ex laoreet molestie. Sit eu sint inermis. Ea zzril scribentur pro.</p>
            <h1>Tempor essent appetere</h1>
            <p>Ius mutat commune expetendis in. Nam et quas sensibus reprimique, vix no erat soluta suavitate. At mel eius dictas latine. Corrumpit inciderint reformidans sed no, no usu omnis utinam noluisse.</p>
            <p>Sit et, an ius nihil apeirian. Eu posse tempor iuvaret cum. No diam dolor sea, postea mnesarchum ne ius, vel no utinam ignota dolores. Malis suscipit accusamus his ne, utinam assentior prodesset ea eam, facer partem antiopam et cum.</p>
            <p>Blandit insolens constituto vix an. Has diam wisi in, eum unum repudiare no. Sit at virtute rationibus, qui vitae explicari cu. Vim ne singulis voluptatum, sed puto accusata salutandi ei. Ad mel civibus adversarium.</p>
            <p>Per ne solum vivendo, fabulas dolorem vivendo in pro. Nec duis ignota cotidieque no, an per possit nostrum. Pro detraxit definitionem eu. Vivendo officiis no nam, eu has reque maiestatis percipitur, dolore reprimique accommodare cum ad. No utinam voluptua oportere pri, augue sonet dicant ei sea.</p>
            <p>Probo debet quaestio an eos, no mel assum iracundia delicatissimi, rebum facete utroque sed ex. Eu melius invidunt repudiandae vix, eu paulo reformidans deterruisset duo, solum voluptaria efficiantur ea mel. Qui summo zzril alienum et. Eu est ferri iuvaret, mazim epicurei sententiae ut cum, modo reque intellegat ex vix. Vim eu tibique accusamus, quot electram at qui.</p>
            <p>Ex iisque eleifend periculis has. Sit aeterno virtute partiendo ei, eam nonumy bonorum adolescens ad. Ut nec suas vocent ornatus, cetero legendos constituam mea ea, pri cu delenit iracundia. Mundi decore nec te.</p>
            <h1>Soleat civibus in pri</h1>
            <p>In petentium erroribus percipitur per. Takimata accommodare ius ut, eam no postulant urbanitas. Qui ei tantas consectetuer, quis dictas euripidis duo ei. Quaeque democritum concludaturque has ne.</p>
            <p>Blandit insolens constituto vix an. Has diam wisi in, eum unum repudiare no. Sit at virtute rationibus, qui vitae explicari cu. Vim ne singulis voluptatum, sed puto accusata salutandi ei. Ad mel civibus adversarium.</p>
            <p>Ius mutat commune expetendis in. Nam et quas sensibus reprimique, vix no erat soluta suavitate. At mel eius dictas latine. Corrumpit inciderint reformidans sed no, no usu omnis utinam noluisse.</p>
            <p>Sit et, an ius nihil apeirian. Eu posse tempor iuvaret cum. No diam dolor sea, postea mnesarchum ne ius, vel no utinam ignota dolores. Malis suscipit accusamus his ne, utinam assentior prodesset ea eam, facer partem antiopam et cum.</p>
            <p>Per ne solum vivendo, fabulas dolorem vivendo in pro. Nec duis ignota cotidieque no, an per possit nostrum. Pro detraxit definitionem eu. Vivendo officiis no nam, eu has reque maiestatis percipitur, dolore reprimique accommodare cum ad. No utinam voluptua oportere pri, augue sonet dicant ei sea.</p>
            <p>Sit et, an ius nihil apeirian. Eu posse tempor iuvaret cum. No diam dolor sea, postea mnesarchum ne ius, vel no utinam ignota dolores. Malis suscipit accusamus his ne, utinam assentior prodesset ea eam, facer partem antiopam et cum.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

You'll need to download that file since there's no CDN for it so don't forget to change `path-to-local-file` to the actual location of the file.

For others who only need to support 10+, the problem here is that you're only using the vendor-prefix versions of the CSS. You need to include the normal version as well:

```
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-webkit-column-width: 300px;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-width: 300px;
-moz-column-gap: 40px;
column-fill: auto;
column-width: 300px;
column-gap: 40px;
```

This worked for me in IE11:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".RightArrow ").click(function() {
    $(".columns").animate({
      scrollLeft: '+=500'
    }, 100);
  });

  $(".LeftArrow ").click(function() {
    $(".columns").animate({
      scrollLeft: '-=500'
    }, 100);
  });



}); //end script
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
.columns {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: 300px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-width: 300px;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  column-fill: auto;
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.notsectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.arrows {
  width: 500px;
}
.RightArrow {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.LeftArrow {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns">



  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">1</span>
NUM 1
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>


  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">2</span>
NUM 2
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>

  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">3</span>
NUM 3
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>



  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">4</span>
NUM 4
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>


  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">5</span>
NUM 5
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>

  <p>
    <a class="">

      <h2>
<span class="">6</span>
NUM 6
</h2>
      <h3>200 Broadway</h3>
      <p>This transit hub is a contemporary architectural marvel in Lower Manhattan and features a Sky Reflector Net centerpiece…</p>
    </a>


  </p>

</div>
<!--columns-->


<div class="arrows">


  <span class="LeftArrow"> Previose </span>  <span class="RightArrow">  Next </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple and is NO. If you don't want to put some logic in it and divide the results into specific DIVs then you won't be able to get the desired result. sorry :(